# what does mean now/d elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

what exactly is it `now-1d/d` or `now/d` in elastic search, Below is an example query

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "timestamp" : {
                "gte" : "now-1d/d",
                "lt" :  "now/d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it will take the current timestamp(time when your query reaches to Elasticsearch) and deduct the 1 day timestamp and bring the document in that range.

These types of queries are useful when you don't want to specify the exact time and want to get data of last 1 day, 3 day, 7 day, 1 month etc.

As mentioned in [official doc of range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html?ref=driverlayer.com/web?ref=driverlayer.com/web)

> now is always the current system time in UTC.

Taken example from [official doc of datemath](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/%E2%80%A6)

**Assuming now is 2001-01-01 12:00:00, some examples are:**

> now+1h now in milliseconds plus one hour. Resolves to: 2001-01-01
> 13:00:00
>
> now-1h now in milliseconds minus one hour. Resolves to: 2001-01-01
> 11:00:00
>
> now-1h/d now in milliseconds minus one hour, rounded down to UTC
> 00:00. Resolves to: 2001-01-01 00:00:00
>
> 2001.02.01||+1M/d 2001-02-01 in milliseconds plus one month. Resolves to: 2001-03-01 00:00:00

Comment: ı know it,for example, now+10d   but ı confused what does mean now/d or now-1d/d

Comment: @dılosürücü please have a look at official doc of date-math https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/common-options.html#date-math

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. `now/d` means "now midnight UTC". You don't have to "assume" that `now` is midnight, because it isn't. `now` is now, including hours, minutes and seconds. `now/d` is midnight now. `now-1d/d` is last midnight.